# Change the class of a kendo ui cell

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, edit

I have this grid on my application.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TekstenViewModel.Tekst>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' />").Width(10);
        columns.Bound(product => product.Naam).Width(100).ClientTemplate("<div id='editDiv'><div class='inputDiv'><input id='naam' type='text' value='#=Naam#' class='naamInput' ></div><div class='editorDiv'><a class=\"meerActies iconBtn\" onclick=\"openPopupDemo('#: Naam #', '#: ID #', 'Naam')\"></a></div></div>");
        columns.Bound(product => product.Waarde).Width(100).ClientTemplate("<div id='editDiv'><div class='inputDiv'>#=Waarde#</div><div class='editorDiv'><a class=\"meerActies iconBtn\" onclick=\"openPopupDemo('#: Waarde #', '#: ID #', 'Waarde')\"></a></div></div>");
        columns.Bound(product => product.Opmerking).Width(250).ClientTemplate("<div id='editDiv'><div class='inputDiv'>#=Opmerking#</div><div class='editorDiv'><a class=\"meerActies iconBtn\" onclick=\"openPopupDemo('#: Opmerking #', '#: ID #', 'Opmerking')\"></a></div></div>");
        columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<div id='editDiv'><div class='deleteDiv'><a class=\"delete iconBtn\" onclick=\"deleteResourceItem(#: ID #, '#: Naam #')\"></a></div></div>").Title("").Width(10);
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .Groupable()
    .Navigatable()
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).DisplayDeleteConfirmation(false))
    .Events(events => events.Edit("onEdit")).Change("onChange"))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Batch(true)

        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(product => product.ID);
            model.Field(product => product.RESOURCE_SET_ID).DefaultValue(Model.SetID);
            model.Field(product => product.Type).DefaultValue(Domain.Agromilieu2.Common.Objects.Entities.Resources.ResourceType.GLOBAL_RESOURCES);
            model.Field(product => product.Taal).DefaultValue(Domain.Agromilieu2.Common.Agromilieu2Constants.Resources.DEFAULT_TAAL_CODE);
        })
        .Create(create => create.Action(MVC.BeheerTeksten.ActionNames.ResourceItems_CreateUpdate, MVC.BeheerTeksten.Name))
        .Read(read => read.Action(MVC.BeheerTeksten.ActionNames.ResourceItems_Read, MVC.BeheerTeksten.Name, new { setID = Model.SetID }).Data("onReadAdditionalData"))
        .Update(update => update.Action(MVC.BeheerTeksten.ActionNames.ResourceItems_CreateUpdate, MVC.BeheerTeksten.Name))
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action(MVC.BeheerTeksten.ActionNames.ResourceItems_Delete, MVC.BeheerTeksten.Name))
    )     
)
```

I am trying to change the class of the input in the first column by specifying a Edit event in the grid

```
 .Events(events => events.Edit("onEdit").Change("onChange"))

columns.Bound(product => product.Naam).Width(100).ClientTemplate("<div id='editDiv'><div class='inputDiv'><input id='naam' type='text' value='#=Naam#' class='naamInput' ></div><div class='editorDiv'><a class=\"meerActies iconBtn\" onclick=\"openPopupDemo('#: Naam #', '#: ID #', 'Naam')\"></a></div></div>");
```

This are the event handlers.

```
  function onEdit(e) {
        $("input[name='naam']").toggleClass("naamInputEdit");
    }

    function onChange(e) {
        $("input[name='naam']").toggleClass("naamInput");
    }
```

These are the 2 classes.

```
#editDiv .naamInput
{
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
}

#editDiv .naamInputEdit
{
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    width: 500px;    
}
```

And this is a image of the grid when I click in the input.

[image]

When I click in the input, nothing happens, but if I click anywhere in the cell other that in the input, it will change all other cells, except the one I click on.

Here's an example. I clicked on the first cell and it changed the second and all others, for that matter.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

**Only edit function**

```
edit: function (e) {
    alert($(e.container));
    var row = $(e.container).closest("tr");
    alert(row);
    var rowindex = $("tr", grid.tbody).index(row);
    alert(rowindex);
    var colIdx = $("td", row).index($(e.container));
    alert(colIdx);
    var columname = e.sender.columns[colIdx].field;
    alert(columname);

    e.container.find("[name='" + columname + "']").toggleClass('naamInput');
},
```

**Full page code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jayesh Goyani</title>
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example">
        <div id="grid"></div>
        <style>
            .naamInput
            {
                background: blue !important;
                border: none !important;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var crudServiceBaseUrl = "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service",
                    dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products",
                                dataType: "jsonp"
                            },
                            update: {
                                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Update",
                                dataType: "jsonp"
                            },
                            destroy: {
                                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Destroy",
                                dataType: "jsonp"
                            },
                            create: {
                                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Create",
                                dataType: "jsonp"
                            },
                            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                    return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        batch: true,
                        pageSize: 20,
                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                id: "ProductID",
                                fields: {
                                    ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                    ProductName: { validation: { required: true } },
                                    UnitPrice: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1 } },
                                    Discontinued: { type: "boolean" },
                                    UnitsInStock: { type: "number", validation: { min: 0, required: true } }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: dataSource,
                    navigatable: true,
                    pageable: true,
                    height: 550,
                    edit: function (e) {
                        var row = $(e.container).closest("tr");
                        var rowindex = $("tr", grid.tbody).index(row);
                        var colIdx = $("td", row).index($(e.container));
                        var columname = e.sender.columns[colIdx].field;
                        alert(columname);

                        e.container.find("[name='" + columname + "']").toggleClass('naamInput');
                    },

                    toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
                    columns: [
                        "ProductName",
                        { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: 120 },
                        { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: 120 },
                        { field: "Discontinued", width: 120 },
                        { command: "destroy", title: " ", width: 120 }],
                    editable: true
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: HI. Tks for your reply. I'm using  function grid_edit(e) {
            var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
            
            var row = $(e.container).closest("tr");
            var rowindex = $("tr", grid.tbody).index(row);
            alert(rowIndex);
            
            var colIdx = $("td", row).index($(e.container));
            var columname = e.sender.columns[colIdx].field;
            alert(columname);

            e.container.find("[name='" + columname + "']").toggleClass('naamInput');
          
        } but it's not working, it doesn't even do the alerts.

Comment: I have added alerts for every variable. can you please check that in every alert you will get value or not?

Comment: That's the problem, it won' even do the alert. I f I put a alert before your code like alert("something"), it will alert, but not the alerts inside your code.

Comment: Please make any cell in editable than please provide that row's html code. So based on that I will provide solution.

Comment: It works now. This is code I have now   function grid_edit(e) {
            var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
            var row = $(e.container).closest("tr");
            var colIdx = $("td", row).index($(e.container));
            var columname = e.sender.columns[colIdx].field;

            var item = grid.dataItem(row);
            e.container.find("[name='" + columname + "']").replaceWith('<div class="input"><textarea class="textEdit" cols="50" rows="3">' + item.Naam + '</textarea></div>')
        }. Tks.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

On Kendo grid Edit do this,

**Style**

```
<style>
    .naamInput {
        background: blue !important;
        border: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

**Script**

```
edit:function(e){
    e.container.find('[name='naam']').toggleClass('naamInput');
},
```

**Demo:** http://dojo.telerik.com/iVaL/4

Comment: This actually is part of the solution, but not all of it. I'm using Razor, so I changed your code into .Events(events => events.Edit("grid_edit")) and function grid_edit(e) {
            alert(e);
            e.container.find('[name=Naam]').toggleClass('naamInput')
        }. That works, the thing is that it only works on column Naam, how can i get the container naam?? The css is the same, I just need to get the container's name instead of hardcode it. Tks.

Comment: @RuiMartins So what exactly you want? You want to change all input box color or just one input field color.

Comment: function grid_edit(e) { e.container.find('[name=ColumnName]').toggleClass('naamInput') }. I want to do the exact thing for all columns, but I don't know how to get the column name. I tried this.selectedGridColumnName, but it's undefined.

Comment: @RuiMartins if it's all `input` tag then just do this`e.container.find('input').toggleClass('naamInput')`  and it's working fine for all field in your grid.

Comment: @RuiMartins See my Edited Demo.